# Parse array of Date strings Date array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I am receiving this JSON object:

```
response.myDates = [ "2017-11-19T00:00:00.000Z", "2017-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", "2017-12-25T00:00:00.000Z", "2017-12-31T00:00:00.000Z", "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" ]
```

I would like to save all these dates (actually there are hundreds of them) in a Date array `parsedDates` in Javascript.

Is there a simple way to do it without a while loop?

Comment: response.myDates.map(Date)

Comment: Thanks for your response @gurvinder372. Very useful!

Comment: @musefan or simply you can use `map`

Comment: @musefan I bet `map` uses but not OP going to write a `loop` for this.

Comment: @gurvinder372: That doesn't work, [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/yagk8k46/)

Comment: @musefan yeah, i checked as well.

Comment: @musefan  We are here to help... not to criticize.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran: Sometime you have to criticise to help. If someone is doing something wrong do you not tell them they are wrong? Would you just say "well done, keep doing that wrong thing you are doing". Yes, people often don't like criticism and they get in a huff about it, but they end up better off for it in the long run.

Comment: @musefan you deleted your comments... Now you are being nice... good!

Comment: @musefan oh wait... I just found a link for you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: You can add a reviver with the fetch.response.json per [how to use reviver function with fetch.response.json()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58463173/how-to-use-reviver-function-with-fetch-response-json). If you **know** the resonse is only dates, it could be `.then(text => JSON.parse(text, (key, value) => new Date(value)))`, but you might want to test that the value is a valid timestamp first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simple do a map to new Date();

`let results = response.myDates.map(date => new Date(date))`

Comment: I also thought about that, but surprisingly, this outputs an array of strings (!!) Well, at least, it does in a Stackoverflow snippet (I don't really get it)

Comment: Elegant and useful solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Just map over your array :

```js
const myDates = [ "2017-11-19T00:00:00.000Z", "2017-12-08T00:00:00.000Z"],
      datesArray = myDates.map( dateString => new Date(dateString) )
      
console.log(datesArray)
```

Note :

Surprisingly, this Stackoverflow snippet outputs an array of strings (not sure why), but if you run it in your Chrome console or in Codepen, it outputs an array of dates, as it should

Comment: The SO console is it's own environment, it takes some liberties when presenting human readable versions of objects.