# how to use reviver function with fetch.response.json()

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, reviver-function

There is a "reviver" function that comes with **JSON.parse** (eg: ["JSON.parse using reviver function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374186/)).

How can I use this "reviver" with **response.json**? for instance:

```
fetch(url)
.then(a => a.json({reviver}))    // unfortunately not working
.then(...)
```

I have a workaround:

```
fetch(url)
.then(a => a.text())
.then(b => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(JSON.parse(b, reviver))))
.then()
```

but it uses one more step, which seems useless.
Any better idea?

Comment: No need for that `new Promise` wrapper. And of course you don't need an extra `then` call as `JSON.parse` is synchronous, so you can just do it at the beginning of the next `then` callback.

Comment: @Bergi : I do agree with you about the wrapper. But the reviver allows to removing useless properties, resulting in a much lighter object (if huge json files). If the reviver exists with JSON.parse, why not in fetch.response.json?

Comment: Becasue https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/104

Answer (score 10):

Your workaround is basically the best option but as mentioned, the extra promise is unnecessary.

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => JSON.parse(text, reviver))
    // ...
```

Answer (score -5):

You could do:

```js
fetch(url)
.then((response) => {return response.json()})
.then((json) => {console.log(json)});
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: The OP is trying to parse the JSON in a specific way,

Comment: The question asks how to use a _reviver_, the [optional second argument to `JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter), when using `response.json()`. Using `response.json()` **won't work** as it does't take a reviver argument.